# Overhead with multiple MBeans

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans

Do having multiple MBeans pose performance issues?

Trying to track multiple transactions run in the application. I may end creating 30+ MBeans.
I am really concerned if it will be too chatty with JVM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do having multiple MBeans pose performance issues?

No, MBeans themselves are just stubs for JMX access to your application.  You could have performance problems if you are sending back a large amount of data (like 100s of attributes or large arrays or something) or making a large number of requests per second.  But in themselves, the mbeans are typically singletons and are themselves never a performance sink.

> I may end creating 30+ MBeans.  I am really concerned if it will be too chatty with JVM.

Again, unless you are requesting data from those mbeans at some high rate, you shouldn't have a problem.  We have literally hundreds of mbeans in our various and have seen no performance problem with them.

Comment: How about if a third party monitoring is trying to these 30+ MBeans? Would it be 30+ separate calls to the JVM or just one call from monitoring tool to get updates of all the MBeans?

Comment: Depends a lot on the 3rd party tool.  I believe it is a call per mbean, yes. Can you run a performance test with and without the 3rd party tool enabled @HimanshuYadav?

Comment: Not now. Problem is that clients want to monitor these MBeans and sometime in the future I would be developing client specific MBeans. I can test with a 3rd party tool but could not find one. Tried JavaMelody and VisualVM but they don't poll JMX Beans, I always have to refresh the page. Downloaded Splunk but could not configure it for JMX Beans :(

Comment: Can you suggest me how should to do MBeans performance test? I think I can check if its call per mbean by putting a sysout in the getter of MBean attribute. What do you think?

Comment: Jconsole can poll JMX beans but only numbers that it can graph.  This sounds a bit like premature optimization @HimanshuYadav.  Your mbeans aren't going to be a problem until they are hit every other second by a 3rd party tool.  If they are polled every minute or on demand then there won't be a problem.

Comment: If you install the Tracer plugin for VisualVM some of the metrics do the MBeans polling.